# Can't deploy war because ClassCastException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider incompatible javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider

Tags: jpa-2.1, hibernate-5.x, websphere-9

I got this error even i have created a shared lib on was 9, this lib contains all the hibernate 5.4.3 dependency including javax.persistence 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Do you really needs JPA 2.2 ?
I was able to deploy my EAR under WAS 9 using hibernate 5.2.17 (starting from 5.3 hibernate is JPA 2.2 compliant)
WAS 9 it seems compatible only with JPA 2.0 and JPA 2.1

I created the shared lib using following lists of jars

```
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\envers\hibernate-envers-5.2.17.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\jpa-metamodel-generator\hibernate-jpamodelgen-5.2.17.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\c3p0\c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\c3p0\hibernate-c3p0-5.2.17.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\c3p0\mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\ehcache\ehcache-2.10.3.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\ehcache\hibernate-ehcache-5.2.17.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\ehcache\slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\infinispan\hibernate-infinispan-5.2.17.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\infinispan\infinispan-commons-8.2.5.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\infinispan\infinispan-core-8.2.5.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\infinispan\jboss-marshalling-osgi-1.4.10.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\infinispan\jgroups-3.6.7.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\proxool\hibernate-proxool-5.2.17.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\optional\proxool\proxool-0.8.3.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\osgi\byte-buddy-1.6.14.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\osgi\hibernate-osgi-5.2.17.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\osgi\javax.interceptor-api-1.2.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\osgi\org.osgi.compendium-4.3.1.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\osgi\org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\required\antlr-2.7.7.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\required\classmate-1.3.0.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\required\dom4j-1.6.1.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\required\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\required\hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\required\jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\required\javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar
E:\hibernate-release-5.2.17.Final\lib\required\jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar
```

It is important on the Shared Lib def to check "Class Loading - Use an isolated class loader for this shared library"

and on the Applicatiion --> Class Loader --> Class Loader Order --> select Classes Loaded with Local Class Loader First (Parent Last)

I'm looking too to use up-to-date Hibernate 5.4.x (stable) and in the future the 6.x.. but having similar issue 
If eventually you was able to use Hibernate 5.4.x.. can you share ?

Regards